# Remove all duplicate characters in a string?

Tags: php

Say I have the following:

```
$str = "1AAABBCCCDDDDDDD";
```

How can I remove all the duplicate characters in the string? So it would look like this?

```
$result = "1ABCD";
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

All you need is [`count_chars()`](http://php.net/count_chars):

```
$result = count_chars( $str, 3);
```

With the second parameter `$mode` set to `3`, `count_chars()` will output:

> a string containing all unique characters

You can see from [this demo](http://3v4l.org/bTIZC) that this produces:

```
1ABCD
```

Comment: This is actually a better solution than the possible duplicate solution provided by Azodious.

Comment: does this work on special characters? I get a bunch of unicode ��������� trying to sort a list of characters I have.

Comment: This sorts characters, which may not be desired